# Google BigQuery Google Ads import

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, ads, transfer

I tried to set up a Google Ads transfer to Google BigQuery. However, I receive the following errors:
Error while processing report for table 'Placement' for account id ##########. Http(400) Bad Request; AuthorizationError.USER_PERMISSION_DENIED<

Does anyone knows how to successfully transfer data from Ads to Bigquery?

Answer (score 1):

As (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error, I can only think of two areas for debugging this, which are fairly obvious and you may of already tried

1. The account number: Check the Google Ads account/manager (MCC) account is the correct one and its formatting is correct, if you have multiple accounts use the MCC and don't type in multiple numbers
2. The Script: Check the in Scripts from the Bulk Actions category advanced API that you have enabled BigQuery